# Variable Pitch Helices

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, curves

Is it necessary for a helix to have constant pitch? If it is not so, what would be equation of a variable pitch helix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You need to choose an increasing function in the z - direction. for example :

$$\mathbf{f}(t) = \left(10 \cos t, 10 \sin t, t\exp( -.01 t)\right) \qquad $$

Plot out your z-direction curve in the plane first, it shouldn't be too difficult to find what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank You.But will it satisfy the definition of a helix?i.e, does the tangent make a constant angle with the axis?

Comment: Well clearly the pitch changes, I think it's still a helix, it just has variable pitch. There are many alternatives, for instance you can rotate a curve around an axis and build up a helix around that. ( I have done that for  Agnesi' Versiera). But , you might have a very strict interpretation of a helix, in which case I have given the equation of a coiled spring!

Comment: Well, I'm not really sure how to define a helix. Thanks